# How to .replace() only a portion of a word? And extracting integer from string?

Tags: python

Trying to figure out how to only replace a portion of a word using Lists, For loops and .replace(). I am also in the midst of figuring out how to extract an integer from the code in order to +1 and return the number.

So far my code is as follows:

```
dictZero = [ "zero", "none", "nil", "null" ]
dictOne = [ "one", "won", "juan" ]
dictTwo = [ "two", "to", "too", "tu" ]
dictThree = [ "three" ]
dictFour = [ "four", "for", "fore" ]

userInput = input ( "Enter your sentence to inflate: " )

for i in userInput.split():
    for e in dictFour:
        if e in i:
            userInput = userInput.replace ( i, "five" )
    for d in dictThree:
        if d in i:
            userInput = userInput.replace ( i, "four" )
    for c in dictTwo:
        if c in i:
            userInput = userInput.replace ( i, "three" )
    for b in dictOne:
        if c in i:
            userInput = userInput.replace ( i, "two" )
    for a in dictZero:
        if a in i:
            userInput = userInput.replace ( i, "one" )
    #This seems to work but not sure how to assign it back into the Input
    if int(i):
        i = int(i) + 1
        print (i)
print ( userInput)
```

Example:
Input = "Before I go to bed at 1630"
Output = "Befifth I go three bed at 1631"

So the code works as I want it to for the most part. If you enter a word in the list it will replace it with the corresponding word.

BUT! I cannot for the life of me figure out how to break apart the userInput one step further to replace a word such as "before" and have the outcome as "befifth" rather than fifth. Maybe a further if statement with .split() then .join()?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `int(i)` raises an exception if `i` is _not_ an integer.

Comment: That it does, I was just messing around to see if I could figure out a way to pull out the number to be inflated by +1. Clearly not the best option. It works if the input is just a number though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code turns "before" into "five" instead of "befive" is this line of code here:

```
userInput = userInput.replace ( i, "five" )
```

In this context, `i` is the string "before", so you're replacing the entire word with "five". The correct variable to use instead of `i` would be `e`, which is currently the string "for".

```
userInput = userInput.replace ( e, "five" )
```

Now the output we get is "Befivee I go three bed at 1630". Notice the double "e" in "Befivee". This is because you've ordered the words in `dictFour` incorrectly:

```
dictFour = [ "four", "for", "fore" ]
```

Because the shorter word "for" is listed before the longer word "fore", the code will always replace the "for" in every occurence of "fore", thus giving us that duplicated "e" in the output. You have to reorder your lists in such a way that longer words are listed before shorter words:

```
dictFour = [ "four", "fore", "for" ]  # swap "for" and "fore"
dictTwo = [ "two", "too", "to", "tu" ]  # swap "to" and "too"
```

The next problem is your handling of numbers in the input:

```
if int(i):
    i = int(i) + 1
    print (i)
```

`int(i)` will throw a ValueError if the word can't be converted to a number, which crashes the program. Even if the check passes, `i = int(i) + 1` only updates the value of the `i` variable, but doesn't change the number in the input string.

---

The first thing we do to fix the code is to get rid of those numbered lists `dictZero`, `dictOne`, etc. Whenever you have more than 3 variables with a number in their name, that's a sign that you should store them in a list or a dict instead. In this case, since it's critical that the values are ordered correctly, we're going to use a list and sort the numbers descendingly:

```
replacements = [('five', [ "four", "fore", "for" ]),
                ('four', [ "three" ]),
                ('three', [ "two", "too", "to", "tu" ]),
                ('two', [ "one", "won", "juan" ]),
                ('one', [ "zero", "none", "nil", "null" ]),
                ]
```

The descending order is important so that subsequent replacements don't turn "one" into "two" into "three" into "four" etc.

With that out of the way, we can now start fixing the code. Probably the easiest way to do it is to split the user input into a list, and perform the substitutions in that list:

```
words = userInput.split()
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    # if the word is a number, increment it
    try:
        word = str(int(word) + 1)
    except ValueError:
        # if it isn't a number, loop over all replacements and substitute them
        for replacement, words_to_replace in replacements:
            for word_to_replace in words_to_replace:
                word = word.replace(word_to_replace, replacement)

    # assign the updated word back into the list
    words[i] = word

userInput = ' '.join(words)
print(userInput)  # output: Befive I go five bed at 1631
```

Another option would be to substitute all the words in the input string directly and use regex to increment the numbers:

```
import re

for replacement, words_to_replace in replacements:
    for word_to_replace in words_to_replace:
        userInput = userInput.replace(word_to_replace, replacement)

userInput = re.sub(r'\d+', lambda match: str(int(match.group())+1), userInput)
print(userInput)  # output: Befive I go five bed at 1631
```

Comment: I will give this stuff a go and see where I end up. I appreciate your time and efforts!

Comment: I understand your code works flawlessly other than I had to rearrange the list order so it would start from the highest number down. But unfortunately I don't understand it much. Try and except ValueError are out of my league. Very well done and I will try to use what I can from your response. Thank you again

Comment: @Twissted Oooh, thanks for pointing that out. Huge oversight on my part. A dict was a bad choice. Will fix it immediately.

Comment: The dict does work, it's just something I have not learned yet. And it works perfectly if you start from Five > Four > Three > Two > One. I swapped it around and tested it out.

Comment: @Twissted No, dicts are inherently unordered. If it works, it's just a coincidence that the values happened to be ordered correctly. A list is the correct choice in this case. (Upwards of python 3.6 dicts are ordered, but that's an implementation detail. Starting with python 3.7, dicts will officially maintain order.)

Comment: Coincidence works for me at this point. Python is incredibly confusing, logically I understand how something should work. But implementation is something of it's own. Thank you again :)